# It's possible to hide data for sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a query and table like this;

```js
select A.id, A.name, B.value
from tblA A
left outer join tblB B 
on A.id = B.id

--------------------
id | Name   | value
--------------------
1  | Room A | Data 1
2  | Room A | Data 2
3  | Room A | Data 3
4  | Room B | Data 1
5  | Room C | Data 1
```

and I want the output be like this:

```js
--------------------
id | Name   | value
--------------------
1  | Room A | Data 1
2  |        | Data 2
3  |        | Data 3
4  | Room B | Data 1
5  | Room C | Data 1
```

I try to use `DISTINCT` to make it hidden. but seem nothing to be happen. Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Display issues are almost always better suited to the application layer rather than the DBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8.0 or higher, Using LAG window function is one way to achieve it -

```
select A.id, CASE WHEN A.name = LAG(A.name) OVER(ORDER BY A.id)
                       THEN NULL
                  ELSE A.id
             END, B.value
from tblA A
left outer join tblB B 
on A.id = B.id
```

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT does not hide a column value. In MySQL you can use IF and LAG function combination, not display the name when it repeats

```
SELECT A.id,
       IF (A.name = LAG (A.name, 1) OVER (ORDER BY A.name), '', A.name) name,
       B.VALUE
  FROM tblA A LEFT OUTER JOIN tblB B ON A.id = B.id
```